# How to pass relative path in appsetting

Tags: configuration, web-config

> i have following code and when i pass absolute path my project works but i need relative path configuration.ini is a file which is in my current project so when i give absolute path, like this ,the code never runs

```
<app Settings
 <add key="Configuration Path"    value="d:DocsWcfService\Configuration.INI"/>
    </app Settings
```

i need something like this ,is there any way?

```
<app Settings
 <add key="Configuration Path"    value="~\Configuration.INI"/>
</app Settings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~\Configuration.ini");
```

Comment: how do i use it plz explain do i need to write like this <add key="confirmation path"  value=physicalpath/>

Comment: @NitinBourai - No keep your relative path in the web.config like you already have, but when you pull the path from the config instead of using it directly to open the file, run it through `Server.MapPath` and it will resolve the path for you.

Comment: i tried this thing also but as i am changing my architecture from Remoting to WCF i have to make a change at many places,i got the answer and try to change with minimal effort

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for config file before. I was able to use full path and it was working fine. When I try to use relative path , it wasn't able to find my config file. I hope my solution helps you or at least give you an idea.

Try to click file located in the solution expllorer and expand the properties tab to change 'copy to output directory' as 'Copy Always' . As I know VS copy  to file to \bin\Debug folder every time when we run the project, so the relative path of that file will always be the same during development as well as after deployment.

After that below code will be enough

```
<app Settings
     <add key="Configuration Path"    value="Configuration.INI"/>
</app Settings
```